# java.lang.stackOverflow error android

Tags: java, android, random

I am getting stack overflow error in my code. In my program I want to generate a random integers of around 10-15 elements but there sum should be less than 100. Sometimes I am getting the output without any error but sometimes I am getting the error. Please provide if any better solution then this.

```
        for (int i=1; i<= noOfQue; i++)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        AppDelegate.LogE("Random Number Gen in Array - " + randomNum);
        numberSequenceArray.add(randomNum);
        result+=randomNum;
    }

    if(result > 100)
    {
        numberSequenceArray.clear();
        AppDelegate.LogE("Result of Array - " + result);
        genRandomArray();
    }

    else if( result < 100)
    {
        AppDelegate.hideLoadingDialog(getActivity());
        AppDelegate.LogE("Result of Array - " + result);
        final NumberFlash numflash = new NumberFlash(getActivity(),duration , tickingPeriod, min , max, "False", textNo, output, getFragmentManager(),"FingerMaths");
        numflash.start();
    }
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace and indicate which line causes the error.

Comment: Also please show what method and class contains the code.

Comment: The code sample is incomplete, already the second variable is not defined. Please enhance your question.

Answer (score 0):

One issue here is the way you create the random.

```
Random rand = new Random();
```

This should only get called once. When you construct a random with no parameter (no given seed) in a short amount of time, it might end up using the same seed. If it uses the same seed it will generate the same random pattern and create the same integers over and over again. Move it to outside the loop, or add it as a private class field

```
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i=1; i<= noOfQue; i++)
{
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    AppDelegate.LogE("Random Number Gen in Array - " + randomNum);
    numberSequenceArray.add(randomNum);
    result+=randomNum;
}
```

---

I'm assuming the `genRandomArray();` line is a recursive call. The issue with randomness is that its possible that the end condition will never be met. Each time the recursive call happens it adds to the call stack. If enough calls are made this recursion might end up using all the JVM memory, giving a stack overflow.

Try constructing this function using a while loop instead of making it recursive in order to avoid excessive memory usage.

```
Random rand = new Random();
while(true)
{
    numberSequenceArray.clear();
    int result = 0;
    for (int i=1; i<= noOfQue; i++)
    {
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        AppDelegate.LogE("Random Number Gen in Array - " + randomNum);
        numberSequenceArray.add(randomNum);
        result+=randomNum;
    }
    AppDelegate.LogE("Result of Array - " + result);
    if(result <= 100)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `if(...) break;` seems completely unnecessary since it is the last statement in a `while` loop. A carefully crafted `while` condition will have the same effect with much less typing.

Comment: I was actually thinking of modifying the `while` loop rather than using a `do...while`. Of course, that would require moving the declaration of `result` outside of the loop and initializing it with a value that allows the loop to execute at least once.

Comment: Even a `do...while` requires the variable declaration prior to the loop.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I think there's value in the simplicity of `break` here. There's no real gain here other than semantics. Much less typing also seems a little pedantic

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the code you posted is in a method named `genRandomArray()`. When `result` is over 100, you make a recursive call to this method. The stackoverflow occurs because this happens too many times.

Instead of repeating with recursion, you should use an iterative loop. This will use much less memory and avoid the stackoverflow.